# What is '.R' folder and where to look for it?

Tags: r, macos, directory

I am a beginner in R. I use Rstudio on my MAC OSX.

I have no idea what does this mean 'create a folder ~/.R and put a Makevars in it.'

I went word by word and tried creating '.R' in my home(~) directory. MAC doesnt allow it saying "You can’t use a name that begins with a dot “.”, because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name." ( of course!)

Next I tried to look for .R folder, hoping that it might already be there. But couldn't find it anywhere.

Can anyone please explain where is this '.R' folder on our system? Or how is the whole R folder hierarchy is built.

I tried doing this:

> path2 = normalizePath("~/.R")
>
> Warning message:
>
> In normalizePath("~/.R") :
>     path[1]="/Users/as82986/.R": No such file or directory
>
> setwd(path2)
>
> Error in setwd(path2) : cannot change working directory

Problem is I couldn't even find anything on google because looking for '.R' folder threw pretty vague and unrelated results.

Also, would appreciate if I am not directed to any more documentations. Please. And thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to see/alter/create a makevars file. I read this in a comment somewhere ( 'create a folder ~/.R and put a Makevars in it' ). So, I got confused to not find the .R folder .

Comment: Of course, this is because I have very less understanding of Makefiles in R. I am aware that src folder holds Makevars file or it can have a Makefile file ( latter is not encouraged nowadays). And we can dynamically create ( and later remove too) a Makevars from Makevars.in by using a configure script.

Comment: ah ok, no idea about makefiles, since I do not use them on my own, but the issue with not finding the .R folder has to do with the fact that it is hidden. Looking in google for results for "how to show hidden folders mac" should do the job. *edit* just seen 42- has also given a good answer to this.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the Terminal.app to open a Unix console and then type:

```
$ mkdir ~/.R
```

The dollar sign is there to remind you that this is not the R console which has a ">" prompt. (Do not type the "$".) You are going to need to learn a few more lessons about the Unix commands if you plan to compile packages from source. I generally run my Finder with `ShowAllFiles` set to `Yes`.  Do a google search if that is not meaningful to you.

Comment: What about on Windows 10?

Comment: It's not a Unix-alike OS. You need to read the Manuals and install Rtools.exe.

Comment: Ok using `tools::makevars_user()` I found it at  `C:\Users\WoodwardS\Documents\.R\Makevars`

Comment: Right ... and do notice the advice on the help page. The Windows file manager has an equivalent ability to dislay hidden files and folders. Do a search with Google if desired.

Comment: I already had hidden folders showing, but I didn't know what "~" was supposed to mean.

Comment: I managed to suppress the warning by adding `PKG_CXXFLAGS = -Wno-reorder` to `Makevars`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are responding to with that last comment. The `~/` (tilde-slash) is the user node of a directory tree. In a Mac it's generally a shortcut for `/Users/username/`, but that wasn't really the question being asked.